# How do I convert a TranslatableMarkup instance to a string with PHP Strict mode?

Tags: 9

In my ongoing quest to write better code, I have started experimenting with PHP strict mode (`declare(strict_types=1)`).

Apparently [CKEditor5 module does this in core as well](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3250827).

Using strict mode, I was able to fix several issues with my code, but there is one issue I don't understand how to fix properly.

For example, here is a standard custom form validator:

```
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state): void {
    parent::validateForm($form, $form_state);

    $code = $form_state->getValue('code');
    Assert::string($code, 'Invalid email verify code! %s');

    if (strlen($code) >= 4) {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('code', $this->t('The code is 3 numbers or less.'));
    }
```

PHPStan flags the line `$form_state->setErrorByName('code', $this->t('The code is 3 numbers or less.'));` with this error:

> 117    Parameter #2 $message of method
> Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface::setErrorByName() expects string,
> Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup given.

I can fix the error by casting to a string like this:

```
if (strlen($code) >= 4) {
  $translated_error_message = $this->t('The code is 3 numbers or less.');
  $form_state->setErrorByName('code', "$translated_error_message");
}
```

But this seems a bit ugly.  What's the most efficient way to fix this?

Comment: Even if PHPStan flags it, don't do it. For how to handle TranslatableMarkup see the description which pops up in the IDE : *Avoid casting it to a string yourself, because it is preferable to let the rendering system do the cast as late as possible in the rendering process, so that this object itself can be put, untranslated, into render caches and thus the cache can be shared between different language contexts.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting a `TranslatableMarkup` instance to a class (or causing PHP to cast it to a string) means calling `TranslatableMarkup::__toString()` (a method implementing by [`ToStringTrait`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21ToStringTrait.php/trait/ToStringTrait/9.3.x)), which essentially calls [`TranslatableMarkup::render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/function/TranslatableMarkup%3A%3Arender/9.3.x)). The code you are using isn't ugly. It's not efficent, as the documentation for [`TranslatabeMarkup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StringTranslation%21TranslatableMarkup.php/class/TranslatableMarkup/9.3.x) says in the class description. (Emphasis is mine.)

> This object, when cast to a string, will return the formatted, translated string. Avoid casting it to a string yourself, because it is preferable to let the **rendering system do the cast as late as possible** in the rendering process, **so that this object itself can be put, untranslated, into render caches** and thus **the cache can be shared between different language contexts**.

I would ignore what reported by PHPStan, or set it to avoid that particular report. If I had to cast a `TranslatableMarkup` instance to a string, I would use the code you wrote, or similar one, at least because `__toString()` avoids some fatals, which is the reason why `ToStringTrait` is used by Drupal.

Comment: Now that I understand the issue better, I see that this type of PHPStan error is a bug in core caused by incorrect PHPDoc type hints.  The real fix is to update these PHPDoc type hints, for example: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3338439.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the string value of TranslatableMarkup by rendering the value:

```
$form_state->setErrorByName('code', $this->t('The code is 3 numbers or less.')->render());
```

Comment: That is essentially what the OP is already doing, since the `__toString()` method calls `render()`, with the difference that `__toString()` also catches the thrown exception.

Answer (score 0):

There is a placeholder issue for this in the `phpstan-drupal` repo: https://github.com/mglaman/phpstan-drupal/issues/422

So for now, you can ignore such issues in `phpstan.neon`:

```
parameters:
    ignoreErrors:
      # String casts should happen as late as possible. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/312254
      - "#expects string, Drupal\\\\Core\\\\StringTranslation\\\\TranslatableMarkup given#"
```